# $_SERVER and apache_request_headers() persistent across requests?

Tags: php, apache, http-headers

I am doing authentication for a web service in php. When a user authenticates a session is generated. Eventually this session expires and the user needs to authenticate again. The authentication information is sent in the http headers.

But it seems that sometimes the variable $_SERVER (or apache_request_headers()) return some headers that are not being sent by the client in the current request (they were sent in previous requests). For instance sometimes I get the variable $_SERVER['HTTP_RESPONSE'] filled with information from previous requests.

Is it normal for $_SERVER or apache_request_headers() to 'persist' across requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether or not you're using a browser to access the script.

Your 'persistent' headers are probably due to browser caching, but even then I'm not entirely sure what is happening. I've tried running a few tests using Fiddler, but couldn't replicate  the problem.

Maybe try clearing your cache, as different headers might have been stored from previous versions of the script.

But, I would definitely avoid sending authentication params in the headers. Unless you're using HTTPS, they're liable to be sniffed and stolen. Why are you using headers?

Comment: I am using HTTPFox to check the requests. I can see them going out without the Response header. Also I have checked with wireshark.

Comment: But why are you using HTTP headers to send auth info?

Comment: I am sending auth info more or less like described in HTTP Digest. So I am not sending the user and password in clear text to the server, they are hashed. Also this will run over TLS as suggested. The headers will be encrypted like anything else if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I am marking this answer as correct. It is some sort of browser caching or HTTPFox issue that I will have to investigate further. By running wireshark again I could see that the request and response were as expected. This result is different from the one I am seeing in HTTPFOX where the request seems correct but the response is wrong. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Cacheing is usually the problem with things like this.

Comment: just a sidenote, even if the credentials are sent in the body of the request (as a regular post), they're liable to be sniffed, the only way to avoid is as you said by using https.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER` contains information about the server, it doesn't necessarily contain any request/response information, it's persistent across the server life-time (eg, the SERVER_NAME will persist, but has nothing to do with the REQUEST/RESPONSE)

`apache_request_headers()` contains an array of headers which were sent, those may or may not include any cookie and session information - they are dependent on the client which you're using to access the server.

the only thing which persists across requests, it $_SESSION, because everytime you're accessing the $_SESSION superglobal, it fetches the session information which was saved on the file system (basic PHP implementation), some frameworks persist the session in the database (such as Yii).

I'm assuming you want to create a request header based authentication, so what you need to actually do, is parse the request_headers, match those against a legal user credentials, and simply `open_session()`; and put a value in the session which will mark the user as authenticated, any subsequent check, will be made against the $_SESSION superglobal, or against some other-implementation of sessions.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I am doing the auth more or less as you are suggesting. I guess the problem was just the caching of the response.